# $\limsup$ of series

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

> Find $\limsup\limits_{j\to\infty} |a_j|^{1/j}$, where
>   $$a_j = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/j)^{2j}}{e^j}$$

Since the limit of the numerator is $e^2$, is it correct that the $\limsup$ is equal to $0$? How can I write out the formal calculation?

Comment: Note that as written, $a_j$ is a constant.

Comment: I guess this is fine...I wrote the problem exactly as asked

Comment: Then it is poor notation, but as written, the limsup is $1$.

Comment: Hmm,but how does that happen?

Comment: As I noted, $a_j$ is a constant, and for any $a\gt 0$, the limit of $a^{1/j}$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Either a typo or a trick question! As written, $a_j$ is constant. (Note that the summation variable $j$ on the right is a "dummy" variable. And the series on the right converges, after a while the terms are close to those of a convergent geometric series.)

For any $a\gt 0$, we have $\lim_{j\to\infty} a^{1/j}=1$.